# How do I implement Y-combinator in Forth?

Tags: computer-science, forth, gforth

On [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator) there is no implementation of Y-combinator in Forth.

How can I do that? How do I use Y-combinator in Forth? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a Y combinator.  When you apply `y` to an xt, you get another xt back.  When you execute this new xt, it will execute the first xt and pass in the second xt.

```
\ Address of an xt.
variable 'xt
\ Make room for an xt.
: xt, ( -- ) here 'xt !  1 cells allot ;
\ Store xt.
: !xt ( xt -- ) 'xt @ ! ;
\ Compile fetching the xt.
: @xt, ( -- ) 'xt @ postpone literal postpone @ ;
\ Compile the Y combinator.
: y, ( xt1 -- xt2 ) >r :noname @xt, r> compile, postpone ; ;
\ Make a new instance of the Y combinator.
: y ( xt1 -- xt2 ) xt, y, dup !xt ;
```

Use e.g. like this:

```
\ Count down from 10; passed to the anonymous definition.
10
\ Anonymous definition which recursively counts down.
:noname ( u xt -- ) swap dup . 1- ?dup if swap execute else drop then ;
\ Apply the Y combinator and execute the result.
y execute
\ Should print 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.
```

As for why, no practical reason.  It's a way for a function to recursively call itself without explicitly naming the function.  But (standard) Forth has `RECURSE`, even in `:NONAME` definitions.

Answer (score 5):

### Conception

The definition of `Y` combinator word could be very short in principle. For example, using low-level code generator vocabulary in SP-Forth, it can be expressed as:

```
: Y ( xt1 -- xt2 )
  \ xt2 identifies the following semantics: "xt2 xt1 EXECUTE"
  CONCEIVE GERM LIT, EXEC, BIRTH
;
```

And it can be easily understood because of its small size.
Here `CONCEIVE` begins a word definition, `GERM` gives *xt* of the word being defined, `LIT,` postpones a number (from the stack), `EXEC,` postpones execution (of an *xt* from the stack), and `BIRTH` completes definition and gives its *xt*.

```
\ test
:NONAME ( u xt -- ) SWAP DUP IF 1- DUP . SWAP EXECUTE EXIT THEN 2DROP ;
5 SWAP Y EXECUTE
\ Should print 4 3 2 1 0
```

### One step to Standard Forth

Unfortunately, there is no way in current Forth Standard to get *xt* of a word being defined. So, to define `Y` in standard way we should use some kind of indirection. Without `GERM` functionality, the previous definition of `Y` can be rewritten as:

```
: Y ( xt1 -- xt2 )
  HERE 0 , >R     \ allot one cell in data-space to keep xt2
  CONCEIVE
    R@ LIT, '@ EXEC,    \ addr @
    EXEC,               \ xt1 CALL
  BIRTH DUP R> !  \ store xt2 into allotted cell
;
```

### Solution in Standard Forth

And using only standard words it becomes slightly longer:

```
: Y ( xt1 -- xt2 )
  HERE 0 , >R >R       \ allot one cell in data-space to keep xt2
  :NONAME R> R@ ( xt1 addr )
    POSTPONE LITERAL POSTPONE @         \ addr @
    COMPILE,                            \ xt1 EXECUTE
  POSTPONE ; DUP R> !   \ store xt2 into allotted cell
;
```

Certainly, there is no reason to use `Y` word in real code since Forth has `RECURSE` word for direct recursion.

Comment: Non of the words  CONCEIVE GERM EXEC, BIRTH is defined in my SPForth for Windows, so I guess you use the 64-bit Linux version.

Comment: Please use `REQUIRE CODEGEN-WL devel/~pinka/spf/compiler/index.f   CODEGEN-WL ALSO!` in the current version (4.21). Note that [tarball from CVS](http://spf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/spf/) should be downloaded since the installer 4.20 is outdated. For case of tarball UNIX-LINES should be set in [spf4.ini](http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/readme.en.html)

Comment: To use short form of quotation: `'XXX` instead of `['] XXX`, it is need to add `REQUIRE AsQWord devel/~pinka/spf/quoted-word.f`